# Understanding SFH of a product sutured manifold without stabilization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I'd like to understand Juhasz's proposition that

If $(M,\gamma)$ is a product sutured manifold, then 
$$ SFH(M,\gamma) \cong \mathbf{Z} $$.

The main sticking point is this -- we know $(M,\gamma) = (R \times I, \partial R \times I)$ for some compact oriented $R$ with boundary and use $(R,\alpha,\beta)$ as a balanced diagram defining $(M,\gamma)$, where $\alpha = \beta = \emptyset$.

Why is it the case that $\mathbf{T}_\alpha = \mathbf{T}_\beta = \{\textrm{pt} \} \subset \textrm{Sym}^0(R)$? Naively, It seems like $\mathbf{T}_\alpha$ and $\mathbf{T}_\beta$ should be empty. How should I be thinking of this differently? In particular, is there a nice way to see this result without stabilizing another diagram?

Thanks!

Comment: translation: SFH = Sutured Floer Homology